# How to install trading-vue-js plugins in nuxt.js?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I try to make web site using nuxt.js and trading-vue-js plugins like [Tradingview.com](https://www.tradingview.com/).

So I installed trading-vue-js plugins in my project and tried
to make code. but it didn't work and error occurred in 'trading-vue-js' import part. error messages is below.

[error message]
Could not find a declaration file for module 'trading-vue-js'. 'c:/Users/naoyuki/nuxt-website-project/website-project/node_modules/trading-vue-js/dist/trading-vue.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/trading-vue-js` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'trading-vue-js';

I'm not good at English. So I tried to put that code

plugins :[{sorce:'~/plugins/trading-vue-js'}]

to nuxt.config.js.
but it didn't work.
Does anyone advise me?
My code is below.

```
    <template>
    <trading-vue :data="this.$data"></trading-vue>    
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import {Component,Vue} from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
import TradingVue from 'trading-vue-js'

@Component({components:{TradingVue}})
export default class extends Vue{
    data() {
        return {
            ohlcv: [
                [ 1551128400000, 33,  37.1, 14,  14,  196 ],
                [ 1551132000000, 13.7, 30, 6.6,  30,  206 ],
                [ 1551135600000, 29.9, 33, 21.3, 21.8, 74 ],
                [ 1551139200000, 21.7, 25.9, 18, 24,  140 ],
                [ 1551142800000, 24.1, 24.1, 24, 24.1, 29 ],
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to follow Nuxt Plugin flow for implementing vue plugins in nuxt

First `npm install @types/trading-vue-js`

Then create a file `plugins/tradingVue.js`

In `tradingVue.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import TradingVue from '@types/trading-vue-js'

Vue.use(TradingVue)
```

finally in `nuxt.config.js`

```
plugins: ['@/plugins/tradingVue.js']
```

you can read details in [Nuxt Plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have using yarn. 
So I tried 'yarn add @types/trading-vue-js ' but error said 'An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types%2ftrading-vue-js: Not found". ' in terminal.

Comment: If I install traiding-vue-js in yarn, could you teach me install code please?

Comment: Thanks I did it!